# Detecting cancelled request in Play with temporaryFile bodyParser

Tags: scala, playframework, body-parser

If a large PUT/POST operation that uses `Action.async(temporaryFile)` bodyparser is cancelled by the caller, the Action body will execute as normal. There is a `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException` but that seems to happen only on writing the response back to the channel, rather than on the channel being closed before the request is completed.

The only safe-guard I've found is to manually compare `file.length` to the `Content-Length` header and that's not even possible for streaming requests.

Is this intentional and if so, is there some other hook to fail the request before it gets to the action if the channel is closed by the client mid-request?